# UIDocument loadFromContents: is not always called after document was changed on another device

Tags: ios, objective-c, icloud, uidocument

I have a custom UIDocument subclass and implemented `loadFromContents:` and `contentsForType:`.

To detect that the document was changed on another device, I added a delegate to `loadFromContents:` as suggested in the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocumentBasedAppPGiOS/CreateCustomDocument/CreateCustomDocument.html):

```
- (BOOL)loadFromContents:(id)contents ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
    // load from disk […]

    if ([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(noteDocumentContentsUpdated:)]) {
        [_delegate noteDocumentContentsUpdated:self];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

My problem is that when I change the document on another device, I receive document state change notifications (`edit_disabled` followed by `normal`), but the contents are **not** reloaded and `loadFromContents:` is not called.

The contents definitely were updated on disk. When I manually reopen the document through the UI, I immediately see the latest changes.

Other times it works and `loadFromContents:` is called automatically. I can't figure out why it does not work sometimes. Has anybody else seen this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to perform document version resolving manually after the notification and/or reload document after it become in normal state again.

Look at the following `UIDocument` method to simply reload document's content:

```
- (void)revertToContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url completionHandler:(void (^)(BOOL success))completionHandler;
```